# display inline block is not working expectedly

Tags: html, css

I have a list where elements are displayed as inline-block.

Where first child of ul li element li is inlined but other li elements are coming with extra space. As you can see in below image.

[image]

My css for these elements=

```
<ul class="video-list">

        <li><a href="#">
            <div class="videoimg">

                    <img src="/Images/sample.png" height="150" width="150">

            </div>
        </a>
            <div class="info">

                <a href="javascript:;">name</a>
                <div>
                    Channel: <br>
                    By : 
                    <div>
                        Views : 0
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

`li` will be repetitive element.

**CSS-**

```
.video-list {
    list-style: none;
}

    .video-list li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 3px;
        padding: 10px;
        position:relative;
    }
        .video-list li .info {
            bottom:0;
            background:#f5f5f5;
            padding:10px;
            height:120px;
            border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
            border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule you need is `vertical-align`

```
.video-list li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 3px;
        padding: 10px;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top; /* Added*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add vertical alignment

```
.video-list li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 3px;
padding: 10px;
position:relative;
vertical-align:top; /* here */
}
```